# How can I use react with a custom webserver?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, webserver

I want to use React for a project I am working on, but I also want to use an API.
How can I do it?

I have tried to Google this and ask different people, but I have not got a response yet, so I thought I would ask here. I want to use [`express`](http://expressjs.com/) and maybe not use `create-react-app` (as it takes up a lot of storage).

Answer (score 1):

Working on a custom server doesen't preclude the use of an API.

If you want fetch the API from the express server and inject it directly on react frontend you need to enable server side rendering (useful [post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-server-side-rendering)) and pass the data collected as a props from the server (check this [example](https://github.com/Valerioageno/reactix/tree/express/client/server)).

Rather then you can build your react project (using even create-react-app) and build an express server who return the index.html on call.

Personally I prefer the first one solution.